# Web Form- Store image in database

Tags: asp.net

I am writing a program in WebForm. I am trying to write code which gives the user the ability to upload an image file, store the image in SQL Server, and at the same time display it in the page. How can I do that?
I know how to store Text.box, but I am failed to do that for image. I am a beginner programmer.
 I will very appreciate your help.

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
            {
                if(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 102400)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + filename);
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
                }
                else
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 100 kb!";
            }
            else
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only JPEG files are accepted!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to store an image on sqlserver

Comment: Please take a couple minutes and read (how to ask)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] a good question. With that in mind, as it stands your question is difficult to answer.

Comment: Your code is writing a file to disc. Could your post your code for saving to the database?

Comment: Here you have saved image as file on server side. Where is change file to data stream and others to save in database?

Comment: @AndrewWalters:
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MyPrivatemarket;Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO MyPMwithdate (ID, FristName, LastName,BirthDate, City, Street, StreetNum, Mobile, Email, UserName, PasswordNum) 
               VALUES

Comment: @Nizan It looks like it cut off your comment, if Ahmad isn't able to help you out I'll take a look this evening.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code, try it :

```
System.Drawing.Image image;
System.IO.MemoryStream imageStream;
byte[] imageBytes;

// image = your image object
imageStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
image.Save(imageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); // Use whatever format your image is.
imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
// Save imageBytes to a DB column of type VARBINARY(MAX)
```

Also you will need this :

```
use System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(System.IO.Stream stream).
```

Comment: Iam using webform. How can i get to this line:  System.IO.MemoryStream imageStream;